# Pulling out only required JSON data using jolt

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I'm having a hard time getting my JSON transformed using jolt. Here is my JSON:

```
{  
   "totalPages":105,
   "firstPage":true,
   "lastPage":false,
   "numberOfElements":5,
   "number":0,
   "totalElements":524,
   "columns":{  
      "dimension":{  
         "id":"variables/evar134",
         "type":"string"
      },
      "columnIds":[  
         "0",
         "1",
         "2",
         "3",
         "5",
         "6"
      ]
   },
   "rows":[  
      {  
         "itemId":"938410065",
         "value":"1131568",
         "data":[  
            1.0,
            523.0,
            0.0,
            "NaN",
            0.0,
            1.0002442201269182
         ]
      },
      {  
         "itemId":"2011836789",
         "value":"196149",
         "data":[  
            1.0,
            523.0,
            0.0,
            "NaN",
            0.0,
            1.0002442201269182
         ]
      },
      {  
         "itemId":"1400165844",
         "value":"1258290",
         "data":[  
            1.0,
            523.0,
            0.0,
            "NaN",
            0.0,
            1.0002442201269182
         ]
      },
      {  
         "itemId":"4260137693",
         "value":"1382641",
         "data":[  
            1.0,
            523.0,
            0.0,
            "NaN",
            1.0002442201269182,
            0.0
         ]
      },
      {  
         "itemId":"4117340671",
         "value":"941349",
         "data":[  
            1.0,
            523.0,
            0.0,
            "NaN",
            1.0002442201269182,
            0.0
         ]
      }
   ],
   "summaryData":{  
      "totals":[  
         570.0,
         523.0,
         506.0,
         0.9940711462450593,
         482.6580757318888,
         35.30252394415497
      ],
      "col-max":[  
         33.0,
         523.0,
         2.0,
         1.0,
         1.0002442201269182,
         1.0002442201269182
      ],
      "col-min":[  
         1.0,
         523.0,
         1.0,
         1.0,
         1.0002442201269182,
         1.0002442201269182
      ]
   }
}
```

What I am trying to do is just pull out all of the "value" data. For example:

```
{
  "value":"1131568",
},
{
  "value":"196149",
}...
```

I was thinking the jolt would look something like this, to pull out every instance:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
        "*": {
          "value": "value"
        }
      }
    }
]
```

However when I try this on the [jolt validator](https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/) it says it's invalid.

Could someone please help me understand how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "rows": { // here I add key where nested values can be found
        "*": {
          "value": "[&1].value" // without [&1] all values will be written to the same key
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of how this solves the problem to make the answer more useful and easy to understand for everyone. Thank you.

Comment: Here you can find a lot of basic solutions: https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception